# Separating weight of discrete space.

Tags: general-topology, cardinals

Recall that a cover $\mathscr{A}$ of a set $E$ is *separating* if for each pair of distinct points $p,q\in E$ there is $A\in \mathscr{A}$ such that $p\in A$ and $q\not\in A$. The *separating weight* of a $T_1$ space $X$, denoted $sw(X)$, is the smallest infinite cardinal $\kappa$ such that $X$ has a separating open cover $\mathscr{V}$ with $|\mathscr{V}|\leq \kappa$.

A basic fact about this cardinal function is the following: if $X$ is an infinite set, and $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are $T_1$ topologies on $X$ such that $\tau\subseteq \sigma$, then $sw(X,\sigma)\leq sw(X,\tau)$. From this we can deduce that, if $\tau_{cof}$ denotes the cofinite topology on $X$, and $\sigma$ is a $T_1$ topology on $X$, then the relations $sw(X,P(X)) \leq sw(X,\sigma) \leq sw(X,\tau_{cof})$ always hold.

Now, it is straightforward to show that $sw(X,\tau_{cof})=|X|$. My question is: can we determine the exact value of $sw(X,P(X))$?

Comment: $sw(X,P(X))$ is the smallest cardinal $\kappa$ such that $2^\kappa\geq|X|$. I don't know whether you'd count that observation  as "determining" $\kappa$, considering all the independence results about cardinal exponentiation.

Comment: Yes, that would actually count as a valid answer for me! Now, since any $T_1$ topological space $X$ satisfies $|X|\leq 2^{sw(X)}$, it follows that $\text{log}(\kappa)\leq sw(X,P(X))$. How can we show the other inequality also holds?

Comment: $\text{log}(|X|)$ **

Comment: If $2^\kappa\ge|X|$, fix a one-to-one map assigning to each $x\in X$ a function $f_x:\kappa\to 2$. For each $\alpha<\kappa$ and each $i\in 2$, let $A(\alpha,i)=\{x\in X:f_x(\alpha)=i\}$. The $\kappa$ sets $A(\alpha,i)$ form a separating family. Indeed, if $x\neq y$ in $X$, we have $f_x\neq f_y$, so if we choose an $\alpha$ with $f_x(\alpha)\neq f_y(\alpha)$ and choose $i=f_x(\alpha)$, then $A(\alpha,i)$ contains $x$ but not $y$.

Comment: Thank you very much professor.